# The prime counting function has a lower bound of $C\log\log x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I read that using Euclid's Theorem and by induction, a "gross underestimation" of the Prime Counting Function $\pi(x)$ can be stated as $C \log \log X$, i.e there is a constant $C$ such that the number of primes at most $x$ is at least $C \log \log X$. I cannot seem to figure out how to proceed with induction to write this proof.

Answer (score 3):

One way to prove that there are infinitely many primes is to show that the Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ are relatively prime. (Note that the $F_n$ themselves are not always prime). This is because
$$ F_m=F_0F_1\cdots F_{m-1}+2$$
so if $p$ divides both $F_n$ and $F_m$ (with $n<m$) then $p$ divides $2$, which is impossible because none of the Fermat numbers are even. Therefore for each Fermat number we obtain a new prime, so there are infinitely many primes.

This proof can then be turned into a quantitative lower bound for $\pi(x)$: the number of primes $\leq x$ is at least the number of Fermat numbers $F_n\leq x$, which is bounded below by $c\log\log x$ for some constant $c$ (for all $x\geq 10$, say).